# how to solve error from sending email from contact form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send mail from my contact form. But I am getting error.

**contact.blade.php is:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL('send') }}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
    <table align="center" width="400">
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td><strong>Contact No.</strong></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="mobno" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><strong>Email ID</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Message</strong></td>
        <td><textarea name="msg" cols="30" rows="3" required="required"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
```

**web.php is:**

```
Route::POST('send', 'ContactController@send');
```

**ContactController.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\officeholder;
use App\Mail\SendMail;
use Mail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{

public function send()
{
    Mail::send(new sendMail());
}
}
```

**I have created SendMail.php using

> php artisan make:mail SendMail

by my cmd and then App\Mail\SendMail.php is created.**

**SendMail.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Http\request;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;


public function __construct()
{
    //
}


public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this->view('contact',['msg'=>$request->msg])->to('mymail@gmail.com');
}
}
```

**But I got error after click button on form.**

1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\sendMail' not found

in ContactController.php line 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code:

```
Mail::send(new sendMail());
```

to

```
Mail::send(new SendMail());
```

and

```
use App\Mail\SendMail;
```

to

```
use \App\Mail\SendMail;
```

Update:

try this:

```
public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this
             ->view('contact')
             ->with(['msg' => $request->msg])
             ->to('mymail@gmail.com');
}
```

You need to set variables with function `with()`

Comment: @cloudsoft Do you receive  `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SendMail' not found`, or any other error?

Comment: Now its send but screenshot of contact.blade.php has send to my mail. Not the value of form

Comment: but that is a next question

Comment: Please tell me why it happens.

Comment: what does it mean - send screenshot. It code, or view without variables?

Comment: when I click on submit button of form, then mail has send. But not the value of form. I found screenshot of contact.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\officeholder;
    use Mail;
    use App\Mail\SendMail;

    class ContactController extends Controller
    {

          public function send()
          {
              Mail::send(new SendMail());
          }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But App\Mail\SendMail; is working. But sending screenshot of screenshot of contact.blade.php